# Asp.Net MVC Call HtmlHelper with a variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I use HtmlHelper (in Asp.Net MVC 4.5) to create multiple validated fields per class property. Right now, I need to call them all in succession.

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.SomeField)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.SomeField)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SomeField)
```

So instead, I would prefer to just pass the "m => m.SomeField" to a ViewHelper and have it be something like this.

```
@helper FieldHelper([???] ValueINeed)
{
    @Html.LabelFor(ValueINeed)
    @Html.EditorFor(ValueINeed)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(ValueINeed)
}

// And then call the helper with...
ViewHelper.FieldHelper(m => m.SomeField)
```

My question is: Is this possible? What kind of type is the variable? Microsoft documentation says that it's "Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>>" but I haven't been able to construct such an object with the value. Thanks everyone in advance.

Comment: So what do you get from adding this extra layer of abstraction? `ViewHelper.FieldHelper` has more characters so what are you gaining?

Comment: Makes the View code a little easier to skim through. Also, the helper does a little more not showcased here, mainly providing a layout for company branded UI.

Comment: @CodingYoshi I noticed I had forgotten the two other fields from my example, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I would do it through an extension such as `Html.LabelCustomFor` and copy the signature of `Html.LabelFor`. Within this new method add your custom stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with helpers, I'm pretty sure your going to have to create an extension method instead:

```
public static MvcHtmlString FieldHelper<TModel, TItem>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TItem>> expr)
{
  var output = html.LabelFor(expr);
  output += html.EditorFor(expr);
  output += html.ValidationMessageFor(expr);
  return MvcHtmlString.Create(output);
}
```

Then in your view called with:

`@Html.FieldHelper(x => x.SomeField)`

Comment: I remember trying something similar before, but for some reason the "...does not contain a definition for LabelFor" (etc.) problem always comes up.

Comment: More than likely missing `using` statements: `using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;`

Comment: You were correct, I indeed had forgotten an import. Thank you very much, this suggestion worked!